# class with a lot of methods

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a class with a lot of functions in it:

MyClass.cs Methods:

- Login
- Upload file
- Upload Folder
- Upload large file
- Download

and many more.

the problem is that the class grows and grows, and it's starting to be not comfortable to write the whole methods in the same class.

In one hand I want to invoke the functions like:

```
var myclass=new MyClass();
myclass.SomeMethod();
```

but the price is to put all the classes in the same file.

I there any design pattern for this? or any other ideas would be appreciated

Comment: A single class can be written in more than one file, using the partial keyword. However, that often makes the work harder, not easier. You should divide your code into classes based on the responsibilities of the methods. For instance, one class for file transfer, one for login/logout, etc.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't really the best place for design questions like this. See instead softwareengineering.stackexchange.com or codereview.stackexchange.com (the latter only if you can provide a complete working example to illustrate your problem). But, the fact is, if your class seems like it has too many methods, it may well have, and the solution is to break the class down into smaller pieces, using the philosophy of "a type should do exactly one thing, and do it well". Where to draw the line is generally a matter of opinion, but if you're uncomfortable, it's probably time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using dependency inversion?

You can then define your main class such as this

```
public class MyClass
{
    public IUserManagement UserManager { get; set; }
    public IFileManagement FileManager { get; set; }
    public IFolderManagement FolderManager { get; set; }

    public MyClass()
    {

    }
}
```

With these interfaces

```
public interface IUserManagement
{
    void Login(string username, string password);
    void Logout();
}

public interface IFileManagement
{
    void UploadFile(string path);
    void UploadLargeFile(string path);
    void DownloadFile(string filename, string savePath);
}

public interface IFolderManagement
{
    void DownloadFolder(string path);
    void UploadFolder(string path);
}
```

The Bulk of your code then goes into classes which perform a specific task such as this.

```
public class MyFileManager : IFileManagement
{
    public void DownloadFile(string filename, string savePath)
    {
        //Add code here
    }

    public void UploadFile(string path)
    {
        //Add code here
    }

    public void UploadLargeFile(string path)
    {
        //Add code here
    }
}

public class MyUserManager : IUserManagement
{
    public void Login(string username, string password)
    {
        //Add code here
    }

    public void Logout()
    {
        //Add code here
    }
}

public class MyFoldermanager : IFolderManagement
{
    public void DownloadFolder(string path)
    {
        //Add code here
    }

    public void UploadFolder(string path)
    {
        //Add code here
    }
}
```

You can then create your class and call methods likes this

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass()
{
    FileManager = new MyFileManager(),
    FolderManager = new MyFoldermanager(),
    UserManager = new MyUserManager()
};

myClass.FileManager.DownloadFile("myfilename", @"c:\path\to\file.txt");
```

If you wanted, then you could also add wrappers in your MyClass to hide some of the complexity such as this.

```
//Add in MyClass
public void UploadFile(string path)
{
    this.FileManager.UploadFile(path);
}

//Called like this
myClass.UploadFile(@"c:\path\to\other\file.txt");
```

This way, you can delegate responsibility for each functional area to a specific class which is easier to manage.

Comment: that was what I was looking for

Comment: This is just plain Composition using Dependency Inversion. Where is the injection part? Calling this 'dependency injection' is not correct.

Comment: Using a `String` to store a password is not a good idea since it will reside inside the memory for an undefined amount of time as plain text and can be read without any effort. It is highly recommended to use [`SecureString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring?view=netframework-4.8) for this purpose. Just a side note

Answer (score 1):

Just extract the code inside the methods of your `MyClass` to other classes. In `MyClass` you just call/delegate to the other classes.

This way you can reduce the amount of code in `MyClass` without reducing its method list.